# VS Express C#, display constructor(s) to be used in class or called within constructor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, constructor, intellisense

On Visual Studio Express C#, is there a way to display the specific constructor(s) that can be used in a given class or that should to be called within a given constructor?

I am using someone else's SDK and could not guess what to use hence the question.

Within a class I can type `public` and then type a specific letter to get some clues from Intellisense but how can I see all the constructors available for a specific class?

Within a constructor intellisense does not give me what I can call.

Comment: what do you mean by `define`?

Comment: @Totetski where did I use `define`?

Comment: ooops sorry i mean define `reveal`.

Comment: @Totetski I meant 'display' as it is hidden information which was hard for me to find.

Comment: does the intellisense won't help you? when you type this `ClassName hello = new ClassName(` i'm pretty sure intellisense will display all the possible constructor's definition after the open parenthesis.

Comment: @Totetski within a class I can type public and then type a specific letter but how can I see them all? Within a constructor intellisense does not give me what I can call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could view the class in the Object Browser or right click on the base class and select Go To Definition to pull up a metadata file which lists all the classes members including the constructors.